# What does the Eye icon mean on LG phones?

Tags: lg, notification-icons

I see an eye icon at the top of my screen, but without the phone around it, what does the eye icon mean, just the eye icon.

Comment: People who are trying to watch you surreptitiously do not generally alert you to that fact by putting relevant symbols into your notification bar.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot to make sure that it's "without the phone"?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using an LG device and it looks like you have "Smart screen" enabled.

[Here is a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLZ22qNBKaw) about smart screen that might help you understand what is going on. The icon on the top of the screen is not someone hacking you (not saying no one is possibly watching, but this icon does not mean someone is)

Hope this helps.